# How can I get array type by known element type?

Tags: c#, arrays

Lets say I have a type:

```
var elementType = typeof(int);
```

I'd like somehow to get it's array type, which in this case would be:

```
var arrayType = typeof(int[]) // if one dimensional
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `Type.MakeArrayType`.

Comment: Perfect! Thx a lot! Write it as an answer so I could mark it as right. I've been searching for over an hour and found nothing. Thx again

Comment: It took me about 30 seconds, by checking the documentation for the `Type` class and searching for "array" (using IntelliSense on `elementType` to find members with `array` in them would also have worked). If you spent that much time you may as well spend some extra and write up an answer yourself.

Comment: Not arrogance -- an explanation of how to hopefully save time in the future as well as why I would feel bad collecting points for my action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elementType = typeof(int);
var arrayType = elementType.MakeArrayType(/*rank if needed*/);
```